# Google Cloud Load Balancer caching, ban IPs

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storage with Google Cloud Load Balancer with caching. We used it like a CDN for our platform.
The problem is we have a lot of bad traffic (Bot brute forcing request on unknown files) creating a lot of cache miss increasing the cost of the load balancer.
We want to know if it's possible to add IPs on a ban list for the load balancer ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply security policies  to your load balancer as long as it complies to Google Cloud Platform [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#limits).

- It must NOT be a Google Cloud CDN
- It must NOT be a load balancer for Google Cloud Storage

If your load balancer complies with this rules you can do it [creating](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#creating_security_policies_and_rules) and [attaching](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#attach-policies)  Google Cloud Armor security policies to your backend service.

Here is a Google cloud [example to follow](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#create-example-policies) to implement IP's policies to a load balancer.

And [here some extra info](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#use_case_1_limiting_access_to_the_gcp_https_load_balancer)

If your load balancer does **NOT** complies with the above mention policies you can do it with a Cloud Firewall following [this example](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#example_1_deny_all_ingress_tcp_connections_except_those_to_port_80_from_subnet1).

Hope it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, Google Cloud does not offer a firewall for CDN traffic.

*Note: Google has not published information regarding Cloud Armor supporting Cloud Storage CDN.*

The cost for a cache miss is $0.0075 per 10,000 requests. Since this is for non-existent files you do not have egress or cache fill costs. If you have one million requests for non-existent files, this will cost you $0.75. Google Cloud Storage will another $0.40 per 1,000,000 GET operations for a total of $1.15 per million requests for non-existent files.

When Cloud Armor does support CDN, it will cost you $0.75 per million requests (estimated) so it will basically be a wash for you financially to IP block.

Unfortunately, when you have a public service, bad-actors will knock on your door. There is not much you can do at this time. You can either return 404 thru the CDN or return a 403 thru a future Google firewall service. The cost to you will be similar either way.

If these requests are from the same IP(s) and exceed these numbers, I would open a support ticket with Google and ask for assistance. These requests are not a true denial of service, but I would put this into a type of DoS affecting the CDN. Google has some pretty cool stuff in the GFE (Google Front End) that might help.